# Etymology of "i" summation subscript?

Tags: terminology

As in:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n r^i$$

It seems that $i$ is very frequently the subscript of choice in summations.  Is there a historical/etymological reason why $i$ specifically is the default?  Especially since $i$ already has an alternative mathematical meaning as a commonly used constant?  I mean, I would *never* use $e$ as a variable.  Why $i$?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137785/why-are-variables-i-and-j-used-for-counters

Comment: @leonbloy yes, I actually found this question on StackOverflow, saw that the most satisfactory answer was "because of math", and that the CS folks were satisfied with that.  However, I suppose there must be some history for it in the math community as well, eh?  "Because math" isn't exactly a satisfactory answer on MathStackExchange.  :)

Comment: In some branches of math, $e$ **is** used as a variable – for example, in computability theory, which deals with integers and only rarely with the transcendental number $e$. Similarly, $\sigma$ and $\pi$ are used in various fields as variables for permutations and other functions, despite their specialized meanings in statistics and analysis. Context is everything.

Comment: Maybe because it is the first letter of the word _index_.